# Need help to add more function to my sql statement

Tags: sql, database

The below SQL statement should copy some data from database to another, the error is in `Cities` table inside the `Berava` database there is a column called `StateID` which should be insert a value inside. So how can I add give those cities which will be cope from database to another a specific stateID? I have record my screen which i hope will explain more what i am looking for

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq5U_90JiPk&feature=youtu.be

The error message is:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StateID', table 'Berava.dbo.Cities'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

And the statement is:

```
INSERT INTO Berava.dbo.Cities(City)
   SELECT 
       cityName 
   FROM 
       Bank.dbo.cities 
   WHERE 
       stateID = 454
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
INSERT INTO Berava.dbo.Cities (City, stateID) 
   SELECT 
      cityName, 'ARM' 
   FROM 
      Bank.dbo.cities 
   WHERE 
      stateID = 454
```

You need to know that the exception means that you don't `INSERT` a `stateID` into the table, which caused by not selecting it at the `SELECT`.

Comment: Hi @Turtle but this will not work, as i should give a value of StateID for thos data that i want to copy it to "Cities" table into Berava database. the stateID=454 in the above statement is just to mention which data i want to copy it from the Bank db. so the statement should tell the compailar copy those data and also fill the stateID of each new row with value ex. stateID= ARM

Answer (score 0):

As @Turtle said , the error message has shown you where the error occurred.
You should insert both column(City and StateID) into Berava.dbo.Cities.

```
INSERT INTO Berava.dbo.Cities (City,stateID) 
SELECT cityName,'ARM' FROM Bank.dbo.cities WHERE stateID=454
```